Should I use "the" or not in this case?
Grammarly gave me confusing suggestions. It told me to add "the" before "export revenue" here:

The table illustrates export revenue of kiwi fruit from New Zealand to five different nations.

But then later told me to remove "the" before "car production" here.

There were fluctuations in the car production in this country.

Do you have any ideas why? Should I use "the" or not in these cases?

You could omit the definite article in both instances.  But the first sentence is garbled semantically.  "revenue from the export of New Zealand kiwi fruit to five different nations" cannot be reduced to "export revenue of kiwi fruit from New Zealand to five different nations"

Could you tell me how they are different? This is a popular recent test discussed on social media. I read the phrase in a sample answer and thought it was okay. I still haven't been able to identified the incorrect part here.

"export revenue ... to five different nations".

Sorry but it's too vague. I still don't know what you implied

OK, I will spell it out. The revenue from the export of New Zealand kiwis goes to New Zealand, not "to five different nations".   export revenue = revenue derived from export.

Oh I see. So it should be "The table illustrates export revenue of kiwi fruit to New Zealand from five different nations"?

That phrasing is less than ideal because of the position of the prepositional phrases.   I'd abandon the attributive adjective version ("export revenue"):  "The table illustrates revenue  New Zealand derived from the export of kiwi fruit to five different nations" or  "The table illustrates New Zealand's revenue from its export of kiwi fruit to five different nations".

They indeed sound much better. Thank you so much!
